# Estimating the first derivative of a holomorphic function using Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: B(0,1) \to B(0,1)$ be a holomorphic function with $f(a) = 0$ for some $a$ with $|a| \lt 1$. Find an estimate of $|f^{'}(a)|$. Hint: Use Schwarz's lemma on a suitable function.

I found an answer on [Estimates of the value of a holomorphic function and its derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132636/estimates-of-the-value-of-a-holomorphic-function-and-its-derivative). However, I'm not really sure how to apply it on my case.

The first problem I have is, if I have an  $m(z) = \frac{z-p}{1-\bar{p}z}$ as in the answer, my pole $p$ (as far as I understand it) would be $a$. But then, $m(a) = \frac{a-a}{1-a^2} = 0$.

The second problem is to determine $g(a)$ and $g^{'}(a)$, which somehow feels like the beginning problem for the function $f$.

Any tips how to proceed or where I'm maybe wrong?

Comment: This problem is answered by Rudin in the section "An extremal problem" (in the chapter on Maximum Modulus Principle)

Comment: @geetha290krm thank You, I managed to find it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $m(z) = (z-a)/(1- \overline a z)$ you can consider the function $g = f \circ m^{-1}$, which maps the unit disk into itself with
$$
 g(0) = f(m^{-1}(0)) = f(a) = 0 \, .
$$
The Schwarz Lemma can be applied to $g$ and gives $|g'(0)| \le 1$.

Then
$$
 |f'(a)| = |g'(m(a)) |\cdot |m'(a)| = |g'(0)|\cdot \frac{1}{1-|a|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|a|^2} \, .
$$
The bound is sharp, equality holds if $g$ is a rotation, i.e. if $f(z) = c(z-a)/(1- \overline a z)$ for some constant $c$ of modulus one.

This is a special case of the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem): If $f: B(0,1) \to B(0,1)$ is holomorphic then
$$
 |f'(z)| \le \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank You very much!